# What was the question and answer of the exam?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, exam

I have seen the movie *Exam*, where few candidates compete to get a job in a big company, where they have been told to answer a question, In the end a lady gets the answer and wins the competition so, my questions are

1. What was the question?
2. What answer did the lady give?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Question was "Any Questions?" (at 7:47) and the Answer was "No!" (at 1:28:07).